# Update virus definitions for a ClamAV Docker container

Tags: email, docker, updates, clamav

Does anyone know how to maintain a ClamAV container?

Specifically, it's the ClamAV container included with MailCow, but I'd like to use Docker more broadly as well, so how can I keep something like virus definitions, or other updateables in containerized services, up to date?

Can I use a cron process for something like this?

I can't really find a good way to interact with the container's filesystem to do it manually from the host system, and I get the impression that's not the right approach with containers. How should I approach something like this?

Should I pull a fresh container constantly? That worries me about the possibility of introducing new binaries/codebases all the time, and would like to maintain the model of using well known versions of software rather than push containers into production without testing. Ideas?

Thanks in advance -

P.S. - I tried freshclam from the command line, no dice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MJHd,

I am also looking for the same answer and going by description provided in the Overview section, it seems that **freshclam** runs continuously in the background updating the virus signature database. Hope this helps!!!

Reference:
https://hub.docker.com/r/mkodockx/docker-clamav/
[image]

Comment: You’re right - so I guess you would otherwise need to log in and run freshclam manually - but you’re right, it appears in the container’s crontab…